# Two columns, Image Left Content Right - Resize image not content

Tags: html, css

I have a two column layout image left and text content right. When the screen resizes, the text content is resizing. How can I adjust the code so that the image resizes instead of the text?

```
<div class="content-block-container">
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <div class="content-block-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis justo nisl, vel suscipit lectus dignissim
            ut. Aenean sed auctor lorem. Suspendisse eget dapibus est, a egestas dolor. Phasellus lobortis non lacus in sodales.
            Mauris at est justo. Quisque at risus eu odio lobortis suscipit. Etiam nulla elit, tincidunt feugiat nunc a,
            vulputate volutpat lectus. Integer commodo at tellus a tristique. Suspendisse nec sollicitudin sem, non volutpat
            neque. Donec maximus nec purus vel fermentum. Mauris eu nulla efficitur, pharetra dolor fringilla, placerat justo.
        </p>
        <pLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis justo nisl, vel suscipit lectus dignissim ut.
            Aenean sed auctor lorem. Suspendisse eget dapibus est, a egestas dolor. Phasellus lobortis non lacus in sodales.
            Mauris at est justo. Quisque at risus eu odio lobortis suscipit. Etiam nulla elit, tincidunt feugiat nunc a,
            vulputate volutpat lectus. Integer commodo at tellus a tristique. Suspendisse nec sollicitudin sem, non volutpat
            neque. Donec maximus nec purus vel fermentum. Mauris eu nulla efficitur, pharetra dolor fringilla, placerat
            justo.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .content-block-container {
        align-items: end;
        display: flex;
    }

    .content-block-container img {
        border: 5px #fff solid;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }

    .content-block-content {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    img {
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }    

</style>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yourbudweiser/2a0m45pt/1/)

Comment: Are you trying to make the image smaller before the text?

Comment: Yes, instead of the text resizing, i'm trying to get the image to resize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sets a `min-width` of `content-block-content` and `width` of `img` which should do as you are looking for it to do.

Be careful using `img` instead of setting a class (ie `<img class="article-img"`) as this will affect all `<img>` tags.

```css
.content-block-container {
    align-items: end;
    display: flex;
}

.content-block-container img {
    border: 5px #fff solid;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.content-block-content {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
}

img {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-block-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <div class="content-block-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis justo nisl, vel suscipit lectus dignissim
            ut. Aenean sed auctor lorem. Suspendisse eget dapibus est, a egestas dolor. Phasellus lobortis non lacus in sodales.
            Mauris at est justo. Quisque at risus eu odio lobortis suscipit. Etiam nulla elit, tincidunt feugiat nunc a,
            vulputate volutpat lectus. Integer commodo at tellus a tristique. Suspendisse nec sollicitudin sem, non volutpat
            neque. Donec maximus nec purus vel fermentum. Mauris eu nulla efficitur, pharetra dolor fringilla, placerat justo.
        </p>
        <pLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis justo nisl, vel suscipit lectus dignissim ut.
            Aenean sed auctor lorem. Suspendisse eget dapibus est, a egestas dolor. Phasellus lobortis non lacus in sodales.
            Mauris at est justo. Quisque at risus eu odio lobortis suscipit. Etiam nulla elit, tincidunt feugiat nunc a,
            vulputate volutpat lectus. Integer commodo at tellus a tristique. Suspendisse nec sollicitudin sem, non volutpat
            neque. Donec maximus nec purus vel fermentum. Mauris eu nulla efficitur, pharetra dolor fringilla, placerat
            justo.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding a percentage to the image size also causes the image to increase in size as well. I was hoping to avoid setting a size on the image.

Comment: If we throw in a max-width and max-height, that might help

Comment: Edited. Try that

Comment: All together this will work just as I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "width" attribute with precent value into your img tag like this:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="30%">
```

Comment: Adding a percentage to the image size also causes the image to increase in size as well. I was hoping to avoid setting a size on the image.